# What are triggers in package management?

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I notice during a software install or removal that near end of process a trigger is utilized and I am curious as to what these are ?

Answer (score 2):

Triggers are the set of instructions or procedures which are defined and stored somewhere by the system or the user which will be automatically executed whenever any kind of update or operation is performed on a system/database.

So during an update or software removal/installation some triggers are automatically executed to ensure updated database of the system and performance as well.